# In SQL Server, how to use information from complex query on several tables, to extract organized information from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to automatically extract and save to my computer disk some hundreds table from SQL Server. First I created a query that filtered out information from two tables

```
SELECT 
    [dwh].[DimSystem].[SerialNumber],
    [SystemModel],
    [StartDate],
    CASE 
        WHEN EndDATE > '2022-04-01 00:00:00.000' 
            THEN '2022-04-01 00:00:00.000'
        WHEN EndDATE IS NULL
            THEN '2022-04-01 00:00:00.000'
        ELSE EndDATE
    END AS EndDATE,
    [dwh].[DimCustomer].[CustomerName]
FROM 
    [dwh].[DimSystem]
INNER JOIN 
    [dwh].[DimCustomer] ON [dwh].[DimSystem].CustomerID = [dwh].[DimCustomer].CustomerID
WHERE
    SystemModel = 'somodel'
    AND SerialNumber LIKE '9%'
    AND SiteID NOT LIKE '%place1%'
    AND SiteID NOT LIKE '%place2%'
    AND (EndDATE IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(month, StartDate, EndDATE) > 4)
    AND StartDate < '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY 
    CustomerName, SerialNumber, StartDate
```

`SerialNumber, SystemModel, StartDate, EndDATE, CustomerName` are the column returned from the query, which returns about 1000 rows.

In the query results, `SerialNumber` is not unique but it will not appear more than once for same dates gap (StartDate to EndDATE).

In the same database there are some tables containing information, on each of them there are several action columns such as 'act1', 'act2'... and SerialNumber (compatible to the SerialNumbers of above query) and TimeStamp (when those actions occur). Now for each row from the above query I need to orderly collect 'act1', 'act2' and TimeStamp, adding as column the SerialNumber and StartDate and EndDATE..., the conditions are that SerialNumber will match and that TimeStamp will be in the gap of StartDate to EndDATE, it should be ordered by TimeStamp.

For each row of the upper query there are hundreds of thousands rows in the actions tables. So I need to automatically create query for each row than save the result into my computer disk as xlsx or csv file with combination name of the table name let say 'actionA' and the corresponding SerialNumber and StartDate.

`SerialNumber, SystemModel, StartDate, EndDATE, CustomerName, TimeStamp, act1, act2` are the columns desired.

Comment: I don't understand: what is your actual question? It sounds like you might need some joins or cross-joins but it's hard to tell

Comment: for each row of the first query I need to collect all rows from 'actionA' table withe matching SerialNumber and TimeStamp in the gap of the corresponding StartDate to EndDATE, than save it to disk with name combine from table name , SerialNumber and startdate

Comment: Is that not just `JOIN actionA a ON a.SerialNumber = DimSystem.SerialNumber AND a.TimeStamp >= DimSystem.StartDate AND a.TimeStamp < DimSystem.EndDate`

Comment: I think there is a need of CTEs or Subqueries and some kind of for loop, and some how save each table with it's compatible unique name

Comment: So you have multiple similar tables you need to join? Perhaps `UNION ALL` them first in a CTE then join on that. Sample data (as text) and expected results would help immensely, your question is really unclear